# Check whether a given input file in HDFS is being used by any job at a given point in time

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, jobs

If I submit an input file in HDFS and run multiple jobs that access that file, is there a way to check whether the input file is being accessed by any of these jobs and/or by which of these jobs at any given instant in time?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the filename inside the mapper of your job. When this job runs it will print the name and you can find out which file is being used by that job at that time. This is how you can get filename from within your mapper :

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

HTH